# php array of indicies

Tags: php, arrays, optimization, indexing

Does anyone know a better (shorter/more elegant) way than simply writing a loop and building the array by hand to do the following:

I have an array called `$data` and another array called `$indicies`. The `$indicies` 
    array holds a bunch of indicies which I want to apply to the `$data` array to get 
    a subset out.  For example if I ran `array_rand` with a number of elements greater 
    than 1, I would get an array of indicies out but I really want the array of data
    items and would have to loop to build up that sub set.

I am thinking there might be some map reduce way to do this cleverly that I don't know about.  Anyone have any ideas?  Here is an example of what I have to do now

```
$indicies = array_rand($data,6); //get 6 random indicies to the data
$subset = array();
foreach($indicies as $index)
    $subset[] = $data[$index];
```

here is something similar to what I would want to do

```
$subset = $data[array_rand($data,6)];
```

Comment: An example will worth 1000 words, what you have and what you want in short version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't test it, bu should work

```
$result = array_intersect_key(
  $data,
  array_fill_keys($indices, null)
);
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for... I will accept as soon as SO will let me